# Use angular $parser on the server side in Node

Tags: node.js, angularjs, parsing, module

I'd like to use the $parser module of Angular inside an open source library I'm maintaining. The library is a templating engine for .docx . I would like to benefit from the filtering functionality, and also the parser in general (+ operations, dot syntax)

What would be the best way to have access to the module. given that my library should work in NodeJS?

I can already specify a parser like this:

```
doc.parser=function(expression) {
    return {get:function(scope) {return scope[expression].toUpperCase() }
}
```

The parser first param is the expression you would like to parse (for example `user.name`), it returns an object with a get function that you can call, in the same philosophy as the $parser module. The parser I create for now is just a demo parser that shows that you can UPPERCASE all the values of the expression.

I'm seeking for a way to say: doc.parser=$parser(), or something like this, and that should work in NodeJS and in the browser.

I found that file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular.js/master/src/ng/parse.js that is responsible for the parsing, but it needs the $filter module, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the $parse method out of the box from AngularJS

Consider using [Angular expressions](https://github.com/peerigon/angular-expressions) - it does exactly what you want. And it works  on bot server and client side.